# Neo4J/Graph database modeling user devices

Tags: neo4j, data-modeling, graph-databases

I'm attempting to use Neo4J to model user mobile devices. However, I'm a complete newbie with graph databases and I'm a little confused on how to make the connections.

For example:

1. UserA

   - Device 1, OS 1, Carrier 1
   - Device 2, OS 2, Carrier 2
2. UserB

   - Device 1, OS 2, Carrier 2
   - Device 2, OS 1, Carrier 1
3. UserC

   - Device 3, OS 3, Carrier 1
   - Device 2, OS 3, Carrier 1

I need to be able to query the following information rapidly:

- All users with "Device 2".
- What are the different configurations for "Device 2"
- Which users use "Carrier 1"
- etc....

What is confusing me is that I want to connect users with the same device together (ie: Device 1), however, the devices are slightly different (ie: carriers). If I attempt to use the same node, I will lose the information on which path is for which user.

What is the best practice when modeling a graph database? Should I just create different device nodes for different device configurations? Is it bad practice having multiple "Device 1" nodes?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Here a a sample of the data size:
- 80,000+ users
- 1,000+ devices
- 600+ carriers
- 15 OS

Each user has 4+ device/configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie as well, but the best thing to do is to start. This [book](http://graphdatabases.com/) is a great resource for best practices.

I think that you could have different device nodes with properties such as 'os:os1'. And these devices would have a relationship to a carrier node.

For example:
(A) --owns--> (Device 1 os:os1) --uses--> (Carrier1)

Each device would be its own node. Best thing is to play around with it. A good resource for this is to use the [cypher console](http://console.neo4j.org). You can test ideas and share them.

Hope this helps

Comment: But shouldn't the nodes be connected? I thought having it as a property is an anti-pattern because it will be the same data cross multiple nodes.

Comment: For example, the OS is not unique to a device but multiple devices will have the same OS.

Comment: That's true re the repeated data. Perhaps each unique device is a node and the os's are unique nodes. Then each device would have a relationship with the os.